# Giving superadmin global access to client and employee in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to allow superadmin to access all of the accounts like the account of itself, client and employee in other word how to give superadmin universal login.

I am using Laravel 5.4 with mysql.

Comment: can you be more specific? Show us code, db schema, what you have done so far, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement access control list.